# How can I stop processing until setTimeout() is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume this please:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('one');
}, 3000);

console.log('two');
```

I want to print `one` first, and then `two` in the console. current code prints `two` first.

How can I stop processing until `setTimeout()` done?

Noted that, I want to execute `setTimeout()` once. not each 3 sec.

---

Here is my real code:

```
var arr = ['mohammad', 'ali', 'zahra', 'fatemeh'],
  res = [],
  status = true;

function myfunc() {
  if (status == true) {
    alert('test');
    console.log('Engine started fetching a new one!');
    status = false;
    $('.im_dialogs_search_field').val(arr[0]);
    $('.im_dialogs_search_field').trigger('change');
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($('li.im_dialog_wrap').length) {
        res.push($(this.find('.im_dialog_photo').attr('src')));
      } else {
        console.log('There is no result for ' + arr[0]);
        status = true;
      }
    }, 3000);
    arr.shift();
  } else {
    console.log('Engine is bussy!');
  }
}
```

When I call `myfunc()` function, it always throws `Engine is bussy!`. What's wrong?

Comment: Move the code of `two` at the end of `timeout` callback.

Comment: Can you put the `console.log('two')` inside the `setTimeout` function

Comment: you created a global variable named "status" which already used by window, rename it or put it in another scope.

Comment: @K.Angel7 thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('one');
    afterTimeout();
}, 3000);

function afterTimeout(){
    console.log('two');
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

move `console.log('two')` inside `timeout`
Try this

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('one');
    console.log('two');
}, 3000);
```